# PDF of (X,Y) What is Z=X+2Y and joint probability density function of (Z,X)?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

> We have joint probability density function (PDF) of X and Y
>
> $f(x,y) =
> \begin{cases}
> e^{-x}  & \text{for x > 0 ,y $\in$ (0,1), } \\
> 0 & \text{in other case.}
> \end{cases}$
>
> Let $Z = X + 2Y$. Find the PDF of (Z,X) in $\{(z,x)\in R^{2}:0<x<z<2+x\}$

So we don't assume that X and Y are independent. I found marginal PDFs of X and Y from their joint PDF.

$f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-x}  & \text{for x > 0} \\
0 & \text{in other case}
\end{cases}$

$f_{Y}(y)=\begin{cases}
1  & \text{for y $\in$ (0,1)} \\
0 & \text{in other case}
\end{cases}$

and $f_{Y}(y)*f_{X}(x)=f(x,y)$ so X and Y are indepedent so maybe I can find Z somehow from convolution theorem. And I don't know what to do next. Especially when i have to find pdf of (Z,X).

Comment: Use change of variables $(X,Y)$ to $(Z,X)$.

Comment: For detail on StubbornAtom's comment you can use a det formula such as given here: http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/4_4.html  Or you can use the definition of CDF $$P[Z\leq z, X\leq x] = P[X+2Y\leq z, X\leq x] = \int\int_{A} f_{XY}(u,v)dudv$$ for $A=\{(u,v): u+2v\leq z, u \leq x\}$, and take derivative with respect to $z,x$.  Better yet: You can do both and verify they give the same answer.